# how to lifting state up from child component to parent component

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I have a parent class component (Dashboard.jsx),
in this component I call my child component (AddExpense.jsx).

```
<ListGroup.Item>
  <Link to="/expenses/add-expense">Add expense</Link>
</ListGroup.Item>

  ...
  ...

<Card.Header id="content-header">Content</Card.Header>
<Card.Body>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/expenses/add-expense" component={AddExpense} />
  </Switch>
</Card.Body>
```

I want to get title of AddExpense from ExpenseController (laravel) and when I click on "/expenses/add-expense" link , "Content"(header in dashboard) change to title that came from Expense controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Data down, actions up".

You should pass down a callback to AddExpense component props.

```
<AddExpense onUpdateHeader={
  (newHeader) => {
    this.setState({contentHeader: newHeader});
  }
}>
```

within the AddExpense you need to call that callback upon click that you mentioned, with a proper argument (whatever you want to send up to the parent component).

```
<Link href="/expenses/add-expense" 
  onClick={ () => { 
      this.props.onUpdateHeader(headerToSendUp);
    } 
  }
>Link text...</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

@sEver has the easiest solution to implement for what you're describing. If you'd like to make a slightly more involved website (or if you want to ensure that multiple components will all have up-to-date information without having to drill information up and down in React), you may want to look into the older [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or newer [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) libraries. I've only used Flux, so I'll only speak to how Flux works.

You have "stores" that exist outside of your components. These stores contain a state, and it typically makes sense to track state using an id number. For example, if you want to store an object

```
{name: 'foo', text:'bar',value:'baz'}
```

you would store it under an id number in your stores.

```
state = {'1' : {name: 'foo', text:'bar',value:'baz',id:'1'}}
```

You may have as many stores as you like in order to keep your flow clean, but your stores must send their data to the same component, which will then pass the stores data through your child components as props.

This is particularly useful if you need to modify data in one component, then send it to a parallel component, or a component that is several levels up. It is not the only solution, and if you are only trying to send information up a single level, a callback function is probably the best solution.